# How can I deploy my Rank and Retrieve app in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, retrieve-and-rank

team,
how can I deploy my "Rank and Retrieve" in bluemix. I already checked all possible links but those are either old or very confusing.
Please help.

Comment: Hi Chiranjit, welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately, your question is much to broad and is likely to get closed.  Please read the help section to ensure questions you post meet the stackoverflow criteria: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Deploying an instance [Retrieve and Rank](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/retrieve-and-rank/?taxonomyNavigation=apps) in [Bluemix](http://www.bluemix.net) is simply a matter of navigating to the Bluemix [Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/?taxonomyNavigation=apps) and selecting [Retrieve and Rank](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/retrieve-and-rank/?taxonomyNavigation=apps). From here, you can choose a plan and create the service instance for Retrieve and Rank.

Once the service instance is created, you are provided a set of service credentials e.g. api `url`, `username`, and `password`. You can use these credentials the Retrieve and Rank API directly. If you application is also running in Bluemix, you can access the service credentials via the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable.